# how to show return message from webapi action method to my web browser using push notification

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, push-notification

i call simply http://localhost:2788/Home/Status this url as a webapi from postman i post the message and retrn a string now i want to update this string message on my this page  http://localhost:2788/Home/Status using push notofication how i perform this.

```
public ActionResult Status()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Status(string status)
            {

                msg m = new msg();
                m.message = status;

                return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            public class msg
            {
                public string message { get; set; }
            }
```

this is my view page

```
@model  PamPam1.Controllers.HomeController.msg
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Status";
}
<html>
<head>
    @*<script src="~/scripts/model.js"></script>*@

</head>
<body>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <h2 id="status">@Model.message</h2>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Call the controller action using AJAX and cosplay the returned value in the view. All of these in JavaScript

Comment: this api call from another device as a webapi.and webpage update message only to show the admin side webpage browser

Comment: Is it kind of chat application where you want to update the client page when some changes available at the server?

Comment: no its only verify the user means i get a status in the form of user reject,verify user message and show message on browser

Comment: Have a look at SignalR

Comment: NO.i want to perform this without SignalR .is it possible?

Comment: If you send request from one client the response comes back to the same client. So you can not send request from user client and get response on admin client. Either you need to use signalR or you make repeated requests from admin client using JavaScript timer and update the admin UI when you get some data in response.

Comment: i explain that my work is that 1: mobile camera capture the user picture and post picture using webapi and this return status is in the form of reject person,not register.i show this status message on my web page when picture capture and i want to see status on my web page